# connection to Cloudera Impala / Hive outside the cluster

Tags: java, hive, cloudera, impala

i am working with cloudera impala server version 5.4.7
first to make sure the port is open i have validate it with telnet.

```
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(30);
try (java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://12.23.56.789:123456/someName;auth=noSasl"))
{    System.out.println("connected");      }
```

**But i never succeed to connect**

all i get is this error from timeout:

what could be the problem ?
i am using the exact same hive version as the cloudera version

```
  [14 Apr 2016 06:27:26,797] [ERROR] [main] [org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection] - Error opening session
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:475)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:181)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.datorama.core.service.delivery.providers.DatabaseProvider.main(DatabaseProvider.java:330)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://54.69.2.250:21050/sage_global;auth=noSasl: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:486)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:181)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.datorama.core.service.delivery.providers.DatabaseProvider.main(DatabaseProvider.java:330)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:475)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a good deal of querying from outside the cluster using JDBC. While I believe it may be possible to use the Hive JDBC driver, you'll certainly need to set a proper port in your JDBC connections string, likely 21050 for Impala.  You'll need to ensure that your host name (or IP address) points to an instance running the Impala daemon (for Hive you might point to a namenode). My guess is that the port number is wrong, as it seems that the error is simply failure to establish a top connection.

We decided to use the specific driver supplied by Cloudera for Impala, although that may not be necessary. We also set up a load balancer so there is one stable address to direct queries to, rather than requiring the caller to pick a specific Impala instance.  This also spreads the load evenly and let's us make changes in the cluster without external callers needing to change anything.